# Selenium Webdriver with Eclipese IDE - Element should have been "select" but was "span"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My application have dropdown, and I have this problem:
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span"

```
enter code here
@Test
public void cadastrar_serviço_completo() throws InterruptedException {
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://erpforme-hml.alterdata.com.br/");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.id("email-login")).sendKeys("*****");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("*****");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='login-passaporte']")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//conpass[@id='conpass-tag']/div/div/div")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("koopon-cabecalho-navbar-cadastro")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("koopon-cabecalho-navbar-cadastro-estoque-servicos")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.id("koopon-produto-servicos-btn-novo")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.id("koopon-servico-input-valor-unitario")).sendKeys("10");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("select2-koopon-servico-select-lista- 
codigos-servico-container"));
Select combo = new Select(element);
combo.selectByIndex(2);**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK9GF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UnexpectedTagNameException` this exception is displayed when passing the
reference of the WebElement which is not Select type underneath it
A check is made that the given element is, indeed, a SELECT tag. If it is not, then an `UnexpectedTagNameException` is thrown.

So instead of `select2-koopon-servico-select-lista-codigos-servico-container` taking this attribute which is of span if you just pass the `select` id which is `koopon-servico-select-lista-codigos-servico` so the exception will not get displayed

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("koopon-servico-select- lista-codigos-servico"));
Select combo = new Select(element);
combo.selectByIndex(2);

I hope the above statements will help you
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a select it is a span, it should go through in a loop iterating through both spans capturing them with some common attribute, in this way select the one you need under some condition if you wish.

sorry my english.
Example:

```
el= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'select2-election')]")
for span in el :
  if span.text == 'xxxxx':
     span.click()
```